Can we file PCT APPLICANTION AND us non provisional application on separate day claiming priority from US provisional?
Can we file PCT APPLICANTION AND us non provisional application on separate day claiming priority from US provisional

What makes you think it is an issue? Maybe I misunderstand the core of your concern?

Yes, or the same day as long as it is within the one year period. Now there are ways to try to get priority past that time by “restoration of priority” in both the U.S. and PCT.
